# How to center these tabs within the LI Class?

Tags: jquery, tabs, html-lists, center, coda

I have these tabs that I would like centered where the header is. However, when I use  it throws the formatting off and causes it to be simple text and no longer a tab. I'm fairly new, so please forgive my current ignorance.

my code and CSS

[image]

my current result: 
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add the code as text to the question. See [help/mcve] and [ask] for more information on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Give a width to the meniu and then center it using margin

```
.bs_example {
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly would I put this in my style.css?

Comment: Nevermind, this was the fix when i adjusted the width and it worked properly. Thank you!